# Meteor + Cordova : EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: xcode, cordova, meteor

I have a meteor + cordova app that I want to build for iOS. When running the app with Xcode, I sometimes get this blocking error :

```
 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend:
    0x334e1f60 <+0>:  cbz    r0, 0x334e1f9e            ; <+62>
    0x334e1f62 <+2>:  ldr.w  r9, [r0]
->  0x334e1f66 <+6>:  ldrh.w r12, [r9, #0xc]
    0x334e1f6a <+10>: ldr.w  r9, [r9, #0x8]
    0x334e1f6e <+14>: and.w  r12, r12, r1
    0x334e1f72 <+18>: add.w  r9, r9, r12, lsl #3
    0x334e1f76 <+22>: ldr.w  r12, [r9]
    0x334e1f7a <+26>: teq.w  r12, r1
    0x334e1f7e <+30>: bne    0x334e1f86                ; <+38>
    0x334e1f80 <+32>: ldr.w  r12, [r9, #0x4]
    0x334e1f84 <+36>: bx     r12
    0x334e1f86 <+38>: cmp.w  r12, #0x1
    0x334e1f8a <+42>: blo    0x334e1f98                ; <+56>
    0x334e1f8c <+44>: it     eq
    0x334e1f8e <+46>: ldreq.w r9, [r9, #0x4]
    0x334e1f92 <+50>: ldr    r12, [r9, #8]!
    0x334e1f96 <+54>: b      0x334e1f7a                ; <+26>
    0x334e1f98 <+56>: ldr.w  r9, [r0]
    0x334e1f9c <+60>: b      0x334e21e0                ; _objc_msgSend_uncached
    0x334e1f9e <+62>: mov.w  r1, #0x0
    0x334e1fa2 <+66>: bx     lr
    0x334e1fa4 <+68>: nop    
    0x334e1fa6 <+70>: nop    
    0x334e1fa8 <+72>: nop    
    0x334e1faa <+74>: nop    
    0x334e1fac <+76>: nop    
    0x334e1fae <+78>: nop    
    0x334e1fb0 <+80>: nop    
    0x334e1fb2 <+82>: nop    
    0x334e1fb4 <+84>: nop    
    0x334e1fb6 <+86>: nop    
    0x334e1fb8 <+88>: nop    
    0x334e1fba <+90>: nop    
    0x334e1fbc <+92>: nop    
    0x334e1fbe <+94>: nop
```

On line 4 (where the `->` arrow is), I get the message

> Webthread (11): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xa000000c)

It happens every now and then, I can't seem to reproduce it. Can anybody tell me what this error means ?

Thanks !

Comment: I'm getting this too. Execution pauses on xcode. Very annoying.

Comment: I am getting error too.